# Force linebreak after javadoc @see

Tags: java, tags, documentation, javadoc

I want to use the @see tag in javadoc to give a hint to multiple books. Something like this.

```
/**
 * @see "Book 1"
 * @see "Book 2"
 */
 public void complexMethod() {}
```

Javadoc produces html code which separates the two books with a comma. I would prefer to separate them with a linebreak. Any ideas how this is possible?

The only solution I could figure out is to add an extra `<br>` after the first @see tag. But this would lead to an extra comma before the second booktitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You could try using:
/**
 * @see
 * <p>
 *     "Book1" </br>
 *     "Book2"
 * </p>
 */
 public void complexMethod() {}
```